# How to search for positions of multiple values in a 1-dimensional array in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a function that returns the positions of multiple values in an unsorted 1-dimensional array in Google Sheet?

Example (row) array to put in `A1`:

```
={1 , TRUE , "iron" , FALSE , "copper"}
```

Desired output for search keys `{"iron", "copper"}`:

```
{3, 5}
```

because `exact("iron",A3)` is `true`, similarly for `"copper"`, and the output array has the same size as search keys (ie. still 1-by-2).

Desired Output for search keys `{"iron", "copper", "silver"}`:

```
error message of sort
```

because `"silver"` does not match any of `A1:A5`.

`{}` stands for [local arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en).

In other words, is there a function or a combo of functions that fulfills the role of `arrayformula(vlookup(...` for `match()` for un-sorted arrays?

---

Further, is there a method that avoids conversion to string? My concern is the conversion of formatted numeric and date in the range to string would not be robust.

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
="{" & ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,MATCH({"iron","copper"},TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," ,")),0))) & "}"
```

[image]

If your source data contains `{` Carlie brackets then use wild card to match function like-

```
="{" & ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,MATCH({"*iron*","*copper*"},TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1," ,")),0))) & "}"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. {} is for array wrapping. For example, in A1, put ={…} for the example and in B1 put ={“iron”, “copper”}. I shoudlve put string quotes around iron,  copper, etc. I’ll correct that once I am on my desktop

Comment: I clarified the question with an edit. Could you take another look please?

Comment: @Argyll Can you simply your exact input to a cell and expected output to another cell. It would be better if you share a sample google-sheet.

Comment: The input and output are ranges -- multiple cells. The `{}` notation does put everything in a cell. Please see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WFVgkEsyjo9KkeMxBx4jsCyIM-WYunOMqdAL3qqHaVc/) for an example sheet.